# Polyline2D in java

Tags: java, graphics, polyline

What packages do I have to import to draw [`Polyline2D`](http://ptolemy.eecs.berkeley.edu/ptolemyII/ptII8.0/ptII/doc/codeDoc/diva/util/java2d/Polyline2D.html)?

do I have to implement them in my class? does the class have to be abstract? 
I've tried importing all the packages like java.awt.shape. I'm trying to draw a triangle in canvas.

I was starting out with something like this

```
 drawPolyline(g2D,new int[]{25,5,45,45,5,45});
```

Comment: Polyline2D. I saw it mentioned as a way to draw triangles here in this example:http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-graphics/SWT_graphics.html#Drawing%20lines%20and

Comment: also mentioned here:http://ptolemy.eecs.berkeley.edu/ptolemyII/ptII8.0/ptII/doc/codeDoc/diva/util/java2d/Polyline2D.html.

Answer (score 0):

You have non-abstract subclasses of `Polyline2D` that you can use - `Polyline2D.Double` and `Polyline2D.Float`.

Since `Polyline2D` implements `java.awt.Shape` you can use `java.awt.Graphics2D` to render it. For example methods `Graphics2D.draw(Shape s)` or `Graphics2D.fill(Shape s)`.

Comment: yes. I was actually trying the Polyline2D.Float. I'll trying to use the java.awt.Graphics2D.

Comment: @user1066524: Take a look at [this tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/java2d/java2dpart1.html). It demonstrates how to draw a basic Line2D.Double shape.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're new to Java so I'll give you some help for the future as well.

You can use the java API page and look for Polyline2D. It will tell you what package it is in. Just google "java 7 API" to look at java 7.

I suggest you start coding in Eclipse; it has a nice auto import package function. It's either ctrl+shift+o... Or you click on the red dot thing on the left hand side where the error in your code is  and select the auto import fix.

If your class is not part of the standard java packages, you need to add that jar to your project then perform the auto import steps. Here is one implementation of Polyline2D:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Polyline2D.htm

and here is the documentation for another one:

http://chess.eecs.berkeley.edu/ptexternal/src/ptII/doc/codeDoc/diva/util/java2d/Polyline2D.Double.html

For the latter you would need access to the jar where the file is.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am using Eclipse. I tried the auto import but there was no suggested package to import, which was weird because usually it is pretty good at that. I am using jdk 1.7. I was using the Polyline2D.Float

Comment: are you using the one from this package: diva.util.java2d.Polyline2D.Float? Did you add the jar to your project?